# Rails array reject from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out. On my index page I have a switch to hide voted cards. The way kaminari the paginate gem works, if you have voted for the first 10 cards the displayed result on page 1 will be less 10 cards. So I'm trying to remove the cards that a user has voted on if the param exists.

How do I set up the @cards.reject to work with an array of items to be removed?

**cards_controller.rb**

```
@cards = Card.all
@card_total = @cards.count
@three_pics = @cards.sample(3, random: 1)
@new_cards = @cards.last(5).reverse!
if params[:voted] == 'on' then
  @voted = Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id).select(:card_id)
  @cards = @cards.reject { |item| block }
end
if params[:view] == 'new' then
  @cards = @cards.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:limit]) if params[:limit]
elsif params[:view] == 'old' then
  @cards = @cards.order(created_at: :asc)
elsif params[:view] == 'least_pop' then
  @cards = @cards.order(popularity: :asc, created_at: :asc)
else
  @cards = @cards.order(popularity: :desc, created_at: :desc)
end
```

***Update***

Let me elaborate with an example and some updated code

```
@voted_did = Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:card_id)
```

@voted = [1, 3, 8]

@cards = [{"id"=>"1", "event"=>"Some Event", {"id"=>"2", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"3", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"4", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"5", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"5", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"7", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"6", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}, {"id"=>"9", "event"=>"Some Event", ........}]

I'm trying to figure out how to not only remove the id from @cards but the entire array for that id, if it is found in @voted

Answer (score 0):

and what about selecting the cards that are not voted by user?

like: `@voted = Vote.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)`

btw, you never actually sent the block in:

```
@cards.reject { |item| block }
```

block part should be the logic ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on @cards.rejected, I'm still missing something tough. I would think pulling all the votes the user did not cast to remove the cards they have voted on would be a long way around.

Comment: so the part block should contain your logic which can be something like: 
@cards.reject {|item| @voted.include?(item[:id]) }